# Use of Struts in html select

Tags: html, jsp, struts2, struts-tags

I have a problem with a select and the use of Struts.
If I select and change page, when I turn back to the page, the select has not the right selection. Why?

```
<select id="select" name="polizza">
    <option value=""   <s:if test='polizza == ""'  >selected="selected"</s:if> ></option>
    <option value="01" <s:if test='polizza == "01"'>selected="selected"</s:if> >Figlio/Figlia</option>
    <option value="02" <s:if test='polizza == "02"'>selected="selected"</s:if> >Genitore</option>
    <option value="03" <s:if test='polizza == "03"'>selected="selected"</s:if> >Coniuge/Convivente</option>
    <option value="04" <s:if test='polizza == "04"'>selected="selected"</s:if> >Nipote</option>
    <option value="05" <s:if test='polizza == "05"'>selected="selected"</s:if> >Legame affettivo</option>
    <option value="10" <s:if test='polizza == "10"'>selected="selected"</s:if> >Altro</option>
</select>
```

I use this to see if the valu is correct and is always correct. For example if select the first value and change page, when I come back the value is 01.
This is the function:

```
<label id="ciao">
    <s:property value="polizza"/>
</label>
```

Comment: Why don't you use S2 tag for select?

Comment: I want to use html select tag

Comment: What type is your `polizza` in action? Just for fun, try with S2 select tag. It isn't so difficult after all.

Comment: polizza is a String @AleksandrM

Comment: In a jsp I have a little form with name, surname, polizza, ecc.., when I press submit I change page. If I came back to the previous page, all the other information are full but the select is empty.

Comment: Hey, that's my code! :) Andrea Ligios is right, you have a javascript tested on ready, and if I remember correctly some browsers (at least IE, not the latest version) do not run the onload after doing a browser back.

Comment: @PsychoWood: What do you mean by that this is your code? Can you prove it? Any link?

Comment: @PsychoWood your code ? :) Are you colleagues ?

Comment: @AndreaLigios Yes, we are, but Ciro didn't know it yet :)

Answer (score 0):

When you print an attribute with the `<s:property />` tag, this will produce plain text in the generated HTML page, and hence the value won't be sent back with a form submission.

If you send your `polizza` from the first page, through the second action, to the second page, and then you want to resubmit it from the second page to the first action (or somewhere else), then you need to use an hidden element, like follows:

```
<label id="ciao">
    <s:property value="polizza"/>
    <s:hidden    name="polizza"/>
</label>
```

P.S: consider using the `<s:select>` tag for your selects, for a better, cleaner, faster code.

---

That said, if the attribute is correctly passed to the action and to the `<s:select/>`, but the selection is wrong, this means that there is some JavaScript changing the selection at runtime, **after** the `<s:select/>` tag rendered the element's HTML.

Comment: using: <select id=polizza name="polizza">
<option <s:if test='polizza== "01"'>selected="selected"</s:if>></option>
</select> the selection is not setted but:          <s:if test='polizza == "01"'>right</s:if>
<s:else>noo</s:else> prints the right value. So the problem is in the select not in the variable

Comment: By the way, the problem is in something you haven't posted yet

Comment: Yes @Andrea Ligios , the prolem was a js file that overwrote my selection

Comment: Ah, it was in a previous comment, now deleted. I'll add it to the answer, in case you want to accept it.